# How to indicate that this variable has maximum correlation with another variable

Tags: r

```
     x1=c(55,60,75,80)
     x2=c(30,20,15,23)
     x3=c(42,33,26,68)
     X=data.frame(x1,x2,x3)
    c=cor(X)
    c
    ##         x1         x2        x3
    ## x1  1.0000000 -0.5581804 0.4153564
    ## x2 -0.5581804  1.0000000 0.4512658
    ## x3  0.4153564  0.4512658 1.0000000
```

from above correlation matrix it appear that x1 has higher  correlation  with x3 , x2 with x3 and x3 with x2 .

I created this code to find maximal correlation for each variable as follow:

```
diag(c)<-0
for (i in 1:ncol(X)){

m[i]= max(c[,i])
 }
m
## [1] 0.4153564 0.4512658 0.4512658
```

But how to indicate variables instead of higher value, like this :

```
x3 x3 x2
```

Comment: Try with `which.max(c[,i])` and then use that to get the row names or using `apply` i.e. `row.names(c)[apply(c, 2, which.max)]`

Comment: @akrun , thanks but how to get them as a vector . `row.names` give me variable names not each variable as a vector .

Comment: The output is a `vector`.

Comment: @akrun ,I know your result is a vector but I want each `x3 x3 x2 `  as vector  not name of them because I want use them to calculate another equation . if you do not undrestand me I will update the question . thanks

Comment: The output I get is `row.names(c)[apply(c, 2, which.max)]#
[1] "x1" "x2" "x3"`.  I didn't understand the `each` as vector part.  Do, you want it as a `list`?

Comment: Do you want `x3  <-  c(0.4153564 , 0.4512658, 1.0000000)`

Comment: I forgot about the `diag(c) <- 0;v1 <- row.names(c)[apply(c, 2, which.max)]; lapply(v1, function(i) c[i,])`

Comment: I mean to get orginal values of  `x3 x3 x2 ` ,  x3=c(42,33,26,68)  x3=c(42,33,26,68)   x2=c(30,20,15,23)  .

Comment: I posted a solution.  I think it is better to have it in a `list` instead of vectors.

Comment: @akrun,  thanks for answer . can you help me  how to use your answer in this calculation ` V=mget(v1) `                                                              `ifelse( (V[1] <= median(V[1])) & (runif(length(x1)) < 0.3), NA, x1) `

Comment: I applied  mget(v1) to another dataframe that have 5 variables but it give me this error 
`Error: value for ‘V5’ not found ` how can deal with this error . ok I will accept it .

Comment: Based on your example, it is working.  It can happen if there is one of the variable for which value is not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get the values of the objects using `mget`

```
v1 <- row.names(c)[apply(c, 2, which.max)]
mget(v1)
#$x3
#[1] 42 33 26 68

#$x3
#[1] 42 33 26 68

#$x2
#[1] 30 20 15 23
```